# Do I need port 993 to get email in a WordPress site?

Tags: security, email, firewall, html, wordpress

Do I need port 993 unfiltered to get emails from a WordPress site?

For example, in WordPress I've installed a plugin called "Contact form 7" (CF7) that gives you a basic contact form.

In the plugin settings you can insert your email (say, `example@gmail.com`) and messages left in your WordPress CF7 contact form will be forwarded to your private email by this plugin.

I've filtered all port besides `22, 80, 443, 993, and 9000`.

Do I really need port 993 unfiltered for the trivial contact form behavior I just described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely won't need it.

Port 993 is related to IMAP, which implies email clients (`mutt`, `thunderbird`, ...) connecting to their mailboxes on your server.

Assuming from your question, you're looking to setup a smtp relay, hence do not need to allow in traffic for potential clients - and probably won't have a service listening on these anyway.